# How to create shape in HTML using CSS with browser compatibility

Tags: html, css, shapes

I want to create a shape in HTML using CSS like this

[image]

How can I create this shape in HTML using CSS. Any best solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS clip-path:

```css
.yourclass {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange; 
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 60% 0, 0 60%, 0 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 60% 0, 0 60%, 0 20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="yourclass"></div>
```

Play around with it on [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).